# JQuery: unable to retrieve username and password

Tags: jquery

For some reason i can't seem to get the username and password that is being entered. Here is my code:

//html

```
<div class="loginForm"> 
<div id="username">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email address"  required />
</div>

 <div id="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" required />
 </div>

 <div id="loginButton"><div id="loginText"><span>Login</span></div></div>
```

javascript

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(){
var usr = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
alert("user=" + usr + " and password=" + password);
});
```

pretty straight forward but for some reason it always comes up blank.

i created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pr1yLdLt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var usr = $("#username").val();`

it's point to a div, a div with id="username", you need to point to `<input>` so write this:

```
<div class="loginForm">
    <div>    
        <input id="username" name="username" type="email" placeholder="email address"  required />  
    </div> 
    <div> 
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" required />   
    </div> 
    <div id="loginButton"><div id="loginText"><span>Login To Meecal</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay i see. Weird, i guess i assumed whatever was under the div would be caught. interesting. Thanks very much all of you :)

Comment: yes! you can surfing by the code using var $content = $("#id"); and then var $mydiv = $content.find("div#key"); $mydiv.find("input").each( ... do something ... );

Comment: @stingMantis please choose one answer like correct if someone answered what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function(){
   //val() is for inputs and the like and your selector is not getting the input
   var usr = $("#username").find('input').val();
   var password = $("#password").find('input').val();
   alert("user=" + usr + " and password=" + password);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give the id to `input` instead of `div`

```
<div class="loginForm"> 
    <div >
      <input id="username" type="email" placeholder="email address"  required />
    </div>

     <div >
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" required />
     </div>

     <div id="loginButton"><div id="loginText"><span>Login To Meecal</span></div></div>
```